# Copy files to s3 from local and delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to sync the files to s3 and then need to delete in the source.Can someone help me with the script or command?

Answer (score 1):

```
aws s3 sync /Path/to/local/dir s3://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME ;

rm -rf /Path/to/local/dir/*
```

Make sure you have the right permissions (policy document) to upload on that bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to upload backup file to S3 bucket

```
    $awsAccessKey = AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
    $awsSecretKey = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
    $bucket = AWS_BUCKET_NAME;
    $zipfile = 'path for your zip file';

    $s3 = new \S3($awsAccessKey, $awsSecretKey);

    $s3->putBucket($bucket, \S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

    $s3->putObjectFile($path."/".$zipfile, $bucket , $zipfile, \S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

and to remove file from S3 bucket below code can be user:-

```
    $awsAccessKey = AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
    $awsSecretKey = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
    $bucket = AWS_BUCKET_NAME;
    $zipfile = 'file name';

    $s3 = new \S3($awsAccessKey, $awsSecretKey);

    $url = "http://".$bucket.".s3.amazonaws.com/".$zipfile;
    if($this->is_url_exist($url))
        $s3->deleteObject($bucket, $zipfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve a data sync. In addition to using scripts for the entire process, you can also use the AWS Import/Export service or Storage Gateway and then automate the source delete after you’ve confirmed the import is complete.  Or you can achieve the [sync with AWS S3](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/synchronizing-data-to-s3-cloud-sync) with third party tools from AWS, NetApp and the like.

If you prefer an open source solution, you can use rclone, which has a clear command line interface, and many commands including delete and purge. For example, the clone command is:

```
Rclone sync source:path dest:path [flags]
```

Rclone also works with many storage solutions including local, Azure, Google Cloud and Dropbox.